# How to get command-line colors for the root user on Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, conemu

I'm using Windows 10 + Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)
to run Kali Linux.
In ConEmu, the color works correctly for a normal user,
but not for the root user.
How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Checkout the differences between bashrc or bash_profile files in user's home folder and root folder.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks, indeed there are lots of difference between the bashrc, about the color, it seems complex, now I'm using ConEmu with fish shell, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

> ### How to get command-line colors for the root user

This question has nothing to do with ConEmu or WSL.
It's a pure Linux/Debian question.
<sup>1</sup>

#### Kali Linux

First back up the original `/root/.bashrc`, so you can restore it
if you change your mind later.
Then copy `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to `/root/` :

```
sudo cp /root/.bashrc /root/.bashrc_orig
sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /root/
```

[image: Commands to introduce color to the root user.]

To restore the original `/root/.bashrc` :

```
sudo cp /root/.bashrc_orig /root/.bashrc
```

#### Ubuntu

Your question doesn't concern Ubuntu, but the above solution should
work for Ubuntu as well.
Here is an alternative solution for Ubuntu.
(It doesn't work for Kali Linux, though.)

In `/root/.bashrc`,
replace `xterm-color)` with `xterm-color|\*-256color)` :

```
sudo sed -i 's/xterm-color)/xterm-color|\*-256color)/g' /root/.bashrc
```

To restore it back :

```
sudo sed -i 's/xterm-color|\*-256color)/xterm-color)/g' /root/.bashrc
```

### Reference

- [List of Debian derivatives](https://www.debian.org/derivatives/#list)

---

<sup>1</sup>
*Debian*, because [Kali Linux is a Debian derivative](https://www.debian.org/derivatives/#list)
(like Ubuntu).

Comment: Upvoted, but (untested personally) I'm wondering if it would be better to do this through `/etc/bash.bashrc` for all users?  I seem to recall that some distributions (Redhat-based, IIRC) do this or some similar mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting suggestion.
Yes, adding the `xterm` colors in `/etc/bash.bashrc` would most likely
be possible – at the expense of a need for a longer answer.
I can see how modifying `/etc/bash.bashrc`
 – or maybe even better `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` – 
could make more sense than modifying `/root/.bashrc`.
I've noticed that on SUSE Linux, the root "prompt" is in red, like in
[this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/llF0cAo.png).
This behavior is apparently out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

For immediate help, just

```bash
source /etc/skel/.bashrc
```